# Opensuse problem with accessing repositories

Tags: opensuse, yast

I have OpenSuse Leap 42.2. YaST2 software manager fails to autofresh and the error message is:

> Cannot access installation media `http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/non-oss/` (Medium 1). Check whether the server is accessible"

This problem has persisted for over a month now.

Any ideas how to get past this issue?

Comment: Is the link working if you try to access in a browser? Also, I'm confused : first you say `I have OpenSuse Leap 42.2 and for a few days now` and then you say `This problem has persisted for over a month now.`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have now edited the post. The link does work in the browser, but it seems that my software manager cannot connect to it.

Comment: The problem has been solved. It appears that the following command did it:

zypper clean --all

If anyone can explain why this works, that would be thankfully appreciated.